# How to get auto complete to work on aliases

Tags: bash, shell-script, autocomplete

I have created some aliases but tab completion doesn't work for them.

I mean I created an alias `impulse` typing `impul`+<kbd>TAB</kbd> gives expected result but after that it doesn't works.

I mean it doesn't shows the prediction or auto completion for that command.

Comment: It's not clear if impul + <TAB> proposes you impulse or not, please clarify your question.

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio yes, typing impul gives impulse

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio problem is that the autocompletion for the command doesn't works like typing impulse and spacing tab doesn't gives the original command like suggestions

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio btw thank you i got the answer